# How do I instantiate an array's size later?

Tags: c++

Let's say I have a base class called

```
Class Base {
public:
    std::string array[];
};
```

The size the string array is not decided until another class extends it, what's the correct syntax for doing so?

EG, later on in a derived class

```
Derived::Derived() {
    array[] = new array[40];
}
```

Comment: This isn't valid C++.

Comment: Consider using `std::vector<std::string>`. Also there is something conceptually *wrong* if the derived type must initialize the base's member

Comment: @KerrekSB
I know =( I had no idea of the correct syntax while posting it, I tried my best to illustrate the idea in as much correct syntax as possible

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you want to use a C-style array, the size must be fixed and **known at compile-time**. And even in that case, you could use the safer, zero-overhead `std::array<>` wrapper instead.

If the size of your container is *not* known at compile-time, then it is good practice to use `std::vector` (or `std::deque` in some cases, based on your requirements in terms of memory allocation) and avoid manual memory management through raw pointers, `new[]` and `delete[]`:

```
#include <string> // For std::string
#include <vector> // For std::vector

class Base {
public:
    std::vector<std::string> myVector;
};
```

Besides, this design won't require any dedicated work in the constructor (and destructor) of `Derived`. If all that was done by `Derived`'s default constructor was to allocate the array, now you can avoid explicitly defining a default constructor at all, and let the compiler generate one for you implicitly - same story for the destructor.

Also, I would discourage you from using names of standard container classes (like `array`) as names for your variables. Something like `myArray` (or `myVector`, as in my example above) are more appropriate choices.

Comment: Can you not change the size of the array in a derived class?

Comment: @GreenDemon if you want to change the size of the vector yourself, you can use `.resize(newsize)`.

Comment: @GreenDemon: You mean, the size of the `std::vector<>`? That is dynamic, so you can change it at run-time at your wish. But the size of a C-style array, or of `std::array<>`, cannot be changed at run-time and cannot be re-defined in the derived class. If you need this kind of flexibility, I guess you'll have to resort to templates

Comment: By using std::vector, I wouldn't even need to declare the size of an array, is that correct?

Comment: If so, then is array[0] = "something"; in the constructor legal syntax

Comment: @Hobbyist: If you do not specify the initial size of the vector in the constructor's initialization list, then the vector is empty after construction. If you want to *add* elements to the vector, you can use the `push_back()` member function, and that will resize the vector automatically for you. So it would be `array.push_back("something");`. But let me suggest you once more to avoid using `array` as the name of your variable: `myArray` or `myVector` is a better choice

Comment: Why do you have a capital C for `Class`?

Answer (score 5):

You don't. Arrays in C++ are of compile-time fixed size. You cannot just resize them to your liking.

The bad way to do this using only language features is to actually have your member as an `std::string*`:

```
std::string* array;
```

And then dynamically allocate an array of `std::string`s, assigning the pointer to the first element to `array`:

```
Derived::Derived() {
    array = new std::string[40];
}
```

The good way to do this is to use library features. The standard library provides container types for you to use. Try a `std::vector<std::string>`:

```
std::vector<std::string> array;
```

Which you could initialise to contain 40 strings like so:

```
Derived::Derived()
  : array(40)
{ }
```

Comment: One can construct-initialize base member in the derived-constructor initialization list ? Allways, in special cases or never?

Answer (score 3):

Why not use a `std::vector<std::string>` so that you don't have to worry about size.  The container resizes automagically as new things are inserted into it.

Answer (score 3):

Using a vector of string is normally better solution.

But this will work:

```
Class Base {
Public:
    std::string *array;
};
Derived::Derived() {
    array = new array[40];
}
```

I'd add:

```
Class Base {
Public:
    std::string *arr;
    Base():arr(nullptr){}
    Base(sizr_t s):arr(new std::string[s]){}
    ~Base(){delete []arr;}
};
Derived::Derived():Base(40) {  }
```

And you may need to write copy/move constructors and asignments. Derived dont have to know about very much. 
Now compare with:

```
Class Base {
Public:
    std::vector<std::string> arr;
    Base(){}
    Base(sizr_t s):arr(s){}
};
```

All other special functions: destructor, copy/move constructors and asignments are generated by compiler. And the constructor of Derived is still:
    Derived::Derived():Base(40) {  }
Also... you may want to make arr private or at least protected?

Comment: I think in the first code example the `array = new array[40];` line should be `array = new std::string[40];`

Answer (score 1):

The correct syntax is

```
std::vector<std::string> array;
```

Comment: No need for trolling. Whether or not to use the vector is an exclusive decision of the implementer.

Comment: @icepack If the implementer needs to ask how to use arrays, he has no business making such decisions.

Answer (score 0):

As well as the done-to-death heap allocation, you can size it statically as in:

```
template <int N>
class Base
{
  public:
    std::string array[N];
};

class Derived : Base<40>
{ ... }
```

Pros: simple, avoids (relatively slow) memory allocation at runtime and the hassles of cleanup (smart array pointer or otherwise).  Cons: each instantiation of Base is a distinct type, which can lead to a little more bloat and less interoperability.

Comment: 5 secs before me :) Just a small comment: in order to be completely compatible with the original requirements, the `Base` shouldn't be instantiable, so its constructor should be defined as `protected`